# How do Stack Machines and 3AC Machines solve expressions?

Tags: stack-machine

So, I'm struggling a little on how Stack Machines & 3AC (Register) Machines interpret expressions. Take this expression for an example:

**4 * 2 - 3**

As a 3AC Machine (instruction sets feature three-operands, a type of Register Register Machine), I think it would look something like this

(Note - I use '#' for comments, pretty sure that this isn't the correct syntax):

*LOAD 4, r<sub>0</sub> # register 0 stores 4*

*LOAD 2, r<sub>1</sub> # register 1 stores 2*

*MUL r<sub>0</sub>, r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>0</sub> # register 0 now stores 8 (4 x 2)*

*LOAD 3, r<sub>1</sub> # register 1 now stores 3*

*SUB r<sub>0</sub>, r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>0</sub> # register 0 stores 5 (8 - 3)*

Sorry about the formatting. I don't know how to get subscripts in code blocks.

I think a Stack Machine would look something like this:

```
LOAD 4
LOAD 2
MUL
LOAD 3
SUB # would this be 8 - 3 or 3 - 8?
NEG # if its 3 - 8 then I need to negate the top
PRINT # outputs the top of the stack
HALT
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  It looks like you've answered the question in the title (or at least one way for each to do it)

Comment: @ChrisDodd Overall, its a check for understanding post. Other, more in particular questions include:

1) What do comments look like for Stack Machines and 3AC Machines?

2) What does 'sub' do for for Stack Machines? Ie is it 8 - 3 or 3 - 8

Comment: machines don't have comments, assemblers have comments.  Assembler comments are all over the map `#`, `;`, `/*`..`*/`, `(*`..`*)`, `//`...

Comment: stack machine binary ops are almost invariably equivalent to 'tmp = pop();  top-of-stack = top-of-stack op tmp;', but the precise semantics depends on the machine